# how to use Windows.Media.Miracast

Tags: uwp, miracast

I find the docs about MiracastReceiver in Windows.Media.Miracast.(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.miracast)
but there are too classes and function in the Windows.Media.Miracast, May take a lot of time to understand these classes and interfaces
Is there any open source code or sample code?

thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

If you want to cast your media, please use `Windows.Media.Casting` namespace to render media on a remote device. Covers sending media to various Miracast devices. This is official [code sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BasicMediaCasting). The following is the sample code. And currently, we have not provided the tutorial or code sample for `Windows.Media.Miracast`. And I will mail to related team discussing this, if we have any updates, I will update below.

```
picker = new CastingDevicePicker();

//Set the picker to filter to video capable casting devices
picker.Filter.SupportsVideo = true;

//Hook up device selected event
picker.CastingDeviceSelected += Picker_CastingDeviceSelected;


private async void Picker_CastingDeviceSelected(CastingDevicePicker sender, CastingDeviceSelectedEventArgs args)
{
    //Casting must occur from the UI thread.  This dispatches the casting calls to the UI thread.
    await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async () =>
    {
        //Create a casting conneciton from our selected casting device
        CastingConnection connection = args.SelectedCastingDevice.CreateCastingConnection();

        //Hook up the casting events
        connection.ErrorOccurred += Connection_ErrorOccurred;
        connection.StateChanged += Connection_StateChanged;

        //Cast the content loaded in the media element to the selected casting device
        await connection.RequestStartCastingAsync(video.GetAsCastingSource());
    });
}
```

Comment: thank you very much. but we want to develop app that receive miracast from other source device.  Do you know if this（Windows.Media.Miracast） is available? If there is no sample code, can we develop it?

Comment: Currently, we have no such document or code sample you may research it by self

Comment: OK。if we have some problem in the steps, pls help us.thank you very very much

Comment: No bother, please feel free post your requirement.